# Pandas function to return country name using city name

Tags: pandas, geolocation

I am trying to create a column in the pandas dataframe that reads the city name from a column in the same dataframe and outputs the country name.

I tried looking into geolocation but couldn't find an accurate solution other than getting the lat and long of the city and using that lat and long to derive the country name.

Answer (score 0):

What code are you using so far?

Maybe have a second dataframe of all cities/countries and just reference against that?